# how do I correct the routes for a Model called "fax" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I used nifty_scaffold to generate scaffold for a new model called "Fax"

In routes.rb, it creates a resource:

```
  map.resources :faxes
```

But when I do a rake routes, I get this:

> new_faxis GET
>   /faxes/new(.:format)
>   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"faxes"}
>                    edit_faxis GET    /faxes/:id/edit(.:format)
>   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"faxes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom inflection (pluralization to singularization and singularization to pluralization) to Rails. You can find a placeholder file for adding irregular inflections under `config/initializers/` called `inflection.rb`. Paste in this snippet and things should start working as expected:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'fax', 'faxes'
end
```

Comment: Hi, I was thinking that was the problem, but then got confused with faxis -- since I couldn't think of a corresponding singularization/pluarization -- but I think you're right, let me try it!)